# Accessing Prev State

Tags: reactjs, state

Am trying to create dynamic tabs with close button. So if a active-tab is closed, the previously-active-tab becomes active.
Below is my code.,

```
  closeCurrentTab = (toBeClosedTab) => {
    let remainingTabs = this.state.allOpenedTabs;
    remainingTabs.splice(remainingTabs.indexOf(toBeClosedTab), 1);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        allOpenedTabs: remainingTabs,
        activeTab: prevState.activeTab
    }));
  };
```

The value of 'activeTab' state is not changing to the previous value. Can someone help what am missing here.

FYI., The same file has the following code and it works perfectly.,

```
  alterOnUpdate = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      aClick: !prevState.aClick
    }));
  };
```

Comment: Can you include your jsx code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing:

```
activeTab: prevState.activeTab
```

You are just keeping the current value of state.activeTab. This statement makes no sense and even if you remove it the result would be same.

So you need to retain the value of previous active tabs in state as well, and on closing currently active tab, set activeTab to previousActiveTab.

Comment: So you have any idea , how to set the state with previous value ?

Comment: Okay got it. So need to maintain 2 states.